# cannot find indexOf symbol in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a function that will randomly generate letter from the alphabet and the user will need to key in "A" for Vowel Letter and "B" for Consonant. The system will then check if the answer is correct by searching the letter from the array.

However, I'm getting this error:

**Cannot find symbol**

**symbol: method indexOf(char)**

Please check my code below.

```
public static void Exam_LetterType() throws Exception
{
    BufferedReader temp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String Alphabet[]={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
    String Vowel[]={"a","e","i","o","u"};
    String Consonant[]={"b","c","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","m","n","p","q","r","s","t","v","w","x","y","z"};

    Random x = new Random();

    int Index;
    String Answer;

    int CorrectAnswer = 0;

    for(int i=1;i<=20;i++)
    {
        Index = x.nextInt(26);

        System.out.println ("\n         A) VOWEL LETTER        B) CONSONANT LETTER");
        System.out.print("         Letter" + "'" + Alphabet[Index] + "'" + " is a: ");

        String Question = Alphabet[Index];  

        Answer = temp.readLine();

        if(Vowel.indexOf(Question).equals(-1))
            if(Answer.equals("B"))
            {
                CorrectAnswer = CorrectAnswer + 1;
            }
            else if(Consonant.indexOf(Question).equals(-1))
            {
                    if(Answer.equals("A"))
                    {
                        CorrectAnswer = CorrectAnswer + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CorrectAnswer = CorrectAnswer + 0;
                    }   
            }   
    }
}
```

Looking forward to your response. Thanks!

Comment: Your code would be mush easier for us to follow if you used the convention is starting variable names with a lowercase. e.g. `vowel` instead of `Vowel` - with the capital it looks like a type rather than a variable.

Comment: will do it moving forward. thanks @John3136!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure arrays are sorted and use Arrays.binarySearch

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is no `indexOf` method in [Array class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html).

And even here

```
if(Vowel.indexOf(Question).equals(-1))
```

you cannot compare  integer values with `equals`  you should use `==`

That line should be

```
if(// check here that weather the value **i** lesser than the length of array)
    if(Vowel[i].indexOf(Question)== -1))
```

That's solves,
Since you are comparing many times, Simply write a Util method, which checks the string is there in `array` or not.

```
 public boolean arrayContainsString(String[] arrayToLookUp, String str){
        boolean contains = false;
        for (String item : arrayToLookUp) {
            if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(item)) { //case or not
                contains = true;
                break; // No need to look further.
            } 
        }
        return contains;
    }
```

Then you can use that method like ,simply

```
if(arrayContainsString(Vowel, Question)){
   //proceed furthur
}
```

And as a **side note:** Please follow [java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).varaibles names starts with lower case letter.

Comment: This will solve his compiler issue, but not his logic. Hes trying to check if the String `Question` is there in the Array `Vowel` or not. Your solution is checking if the String in `Vowel[i]` is in the String `Question` or not.

Comment: Makes no difference.  Both are single characters.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if(Arrays.asList(Vowel).contains(Question))
```

Answer (score 0):

try out this..

you need to change two condition shown below

```
Vowel[i].indexOf(Question) == -1
```

and

```
Consonant[i].indexOf(Question) == -1
```

you can find complete edited code below:

```
public static void Exam_LetterType() throws Exception
{
    BufferedReader temp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String Alphabet[]={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
        String Vowel[]={"a","e","i","o","u"};
        String Consonant[]={"b","c","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","m","n","p","q","r","s","t","v","w","x","y","z"};

        Random x = new Random();

        int Index;
        String Answer;

        int CorrectAnswer = 0;

        for(int i=1;i<=20;i++)
        {
            Index = x.nextInt(26);

            System.out.println ("\n         A) VOWEL LETTER        B) CONSONANT LETTER");
            System.out.print("         Letter" + "'" + Alphabet[Index] + "'" + " is a: ");

            String Question = Alphabet[Index];  

            Answer = temp.readLine();

            if(Vowel[i].indexOf(Question) == -1)
                if(Answer.equals("B"))
                {
                    CorrectAnswer = CorrectAnswer + 1;
                }
                else if(Consonant[i].indexOf(Question) == -1)
                {
                        if(Answer.equals("A"))
                        {
                            CorrectAnswer = CorrectAnswer + 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            CorrectAnswer = CorrectAnswer + 0;
                        }   
                }   
        }}
```